# In a perl string, how can I replace a unicode em dash with 2 ascii hyphens?

Tags: perl, unicode

I first just tried to find it in a line using:

```
    $w = index($line, "\x{2014}");
```

I got no syntax error, but $w was never >= 0.

I tried:

```
    $line =~ s/\x{2014}/--/g;
```

and that didn't work either, ie: no changes were made.

What's the simplest way to make the swap?

If this was explained in prior posts, I didn't see where.

Comment: Check the encoding of your input. If it is UTF-8 encoded, for example, the em-dash will match `\x{e2}\x{80}\x{94}`.

Comment: Good! That works in the call to index, but not in the regex. But that'll get the job done. It's a pity that the documentation doesn't say anything about having to break up the hex into 3 separate characters.

Comment: `$line =~ s/\x{2014}/--/g;` does work, which means that `$line` doesn't contain an em dash. Maybe it contains the UTF-8 encoding of an em dash? Decode inputs, and encode outputs!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use feature 'unicode_strings';
use utf8;

$line = "first — and second";
$line =~ s/\x{2014}/--/g;
print("$line\n");
# => first -- and second
```